# For loops and Dice Roll

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Question is:

> Write a SINGLE LINE OF CODE that will generate a random integer
>   between 1 and 6  inclusive every time it is run. This line simulates a
>   random dice roll.
>
> After getting this random variable, place it in a for-loop that runs
>   for 10000 times. For every run  of the loop, this will generate a
>   random dice roll. Once it is in this loop, we will use it to compute
>   the mean of the 10000 dice rolls. The mean can be simply calculated by
>   taking the sum of all the 10000 rolls, and then dividing the sum by
>   10000. You must make a single variable (call it s) and then update it inside the for-loop, so that when the for-loop ends, you have the sum
>   of 10000 dice rolls in that variable. You can then just go on to
>   divide the sum by 10000 and compute the mean.

The code that I wrote for this question is following :

```
d = 1 + floor(rand(1,6).*6) ;

for i = 1 : 10000
d = 1 + floor(rand(1,6).*6)
s = sum(d)
end
```

I need help to find the sum of a 10000 dice rolls.

Comment: fyi: "runs for 10000 times" - but your for loops only run 1000 times

Comment: And what happened when you ran your code?

Comment: "You can then just go on to divide the sum by 10000 and compute the mean." which your code does not no

Comment: The problem is that every time a new sum comes. I need help in writing a code in which previous sum and new sum gets added up until I have sum of all 10000 dice rolls.

Comment: @Manahil So you're saying that each time through the loop, you want to add `d` to the current value of `s` and make that the new value of `s`?

Comment: yes since due to rand command, each time the loop is run, there will be a different set of numbers from 1 to 6 . So I need each new sum to be added to the previous sum so that at the end of the loop (when it is run for the 10000th time) I have the entire sum (sum of all 10 000 sums)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is the following:

```
s = 0;
for i = 1 : 100000
s = s + (1 + floor(rand(1,6).*6)) % External parenthesis are not required but help to understand it.
end
```

So we are incrementing s (the sum) every iteration with the random value.